# Hide actual URL

Tags: webserver, dns

I have two domains and they are both pointing to one server:

- `http://www.domain1.com/ --> http://www.example.com/`
- `http://www.domain2.com/ --> http://www.example.com/folder1`

How can I hide it so when someone goes to `http://www.domain2.com/` it will come up as `http://www.domain2.com/` in the address bar and not `http://www.example.com/folder1`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with HTML no with programming. You have to configure your server properly. Not sure which tags to put here since it is off-topic.

Comment: If you were "pointing" then the address bar would not show http://www.example.com/folder1, so you must currently be "redirecting". You need to setup your DNS on domain1.com and domain2.com.